# I can not find a pre-trained neural network model for object detection

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection

A simple model is needed, but with good accuracy, mAP for detecting objects is preferably trained on COCO, preferably on ipynb (to run or train on google colab).

The models from the Tensorflow (Faster_rcnn, ssd, R-FCN, YOLO V2 ) will not fit, because need a custom model for example, because I need to develop my own model

Any help?

Comment: So did you build a custom architecture?

Comment: @dcolazin At the moment, no , I need an example of architecture in which I can understand and write my own architecture . Or some kind of detailed guide how to develop an architecture for object detection

Comment: Why aren't the model from tensorflow not good?

Comment: @dcolazin because I need to develop my architecture for a course project at the University. I need to either develop my own architecture or improve the already known architecture. It is quite difficult to understand tensorflow architectures , you need to start with something simpler to understand. I do not want to copy someone else's development , I want to do that my own , but you need to understand not very complex example

Comment: Did you study (slow) R-CNN?

Comment: @dcolazin about vgg not read , thank you, I will read